# Execute a function only when an element with a certain id becomes available

Tags: javascript, function, listener, observers

I have a JavaScript function that should be executed only when an element of a certain id becomes available in the DOM.

Comment: What did you try so far, that didn't work?

Comment: Nothing, I have absolutely no idea where to start. Have you seen MutationObserver API? There are half-burned ancient sanskrit manuscripts that are clearer than that.

Comment: Choice is use MutationObserver or  setInterval that continuously checks for the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation to produce a working example was non trivial, and the [DOM documentation](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-mutationobserverinit-attributes) can provide useful clarification.

It turned out the [`MutationObserverInit dictionary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit) was not an "object type" but just an Interface Description Language (IDL) term used to describe an options object for observing changes - an Object object is all that is required.

FWIW here's an example of detecting adding a new node with, or changing the id of an existing node to, "certainId".

```js
"use strict";
const target = document.getElementById("target");
const observer = new MutationObserver( checkChanges);
const certainId = "certainId";

function checkChanges(changeList, fromObserver) {
   console.log("Callback 2nd argument is the observer object: %s", fromObserver === observer);
   for( let change of changeList) {
      if( change.type == "attributes") {
          if( change.target.id === certainId) {
              console.log("id has been changed: ", change.target);
              break;
          }
      }
      else if( change.type == "childList") {
          for( let node of change.addedNodes) {
              if( node.id==certainId) {
                  console.log("target was added: ", node);
                  break;
              }
          }     
      }
   }
}
observer.observe( target, {
    subtree: true,
    attributeFilter: ["id"],
    childList: true
});

// test
function changeId() {
    if( document.getElementById("test1")) {
         test1.id = "certainId";
    }
}

function insertSpan() { // button click
    if( document.getElementById("test2")) {
       test2.innerHTML = '<span id="certainId">span#certainId<\/span>';
    }    
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
    <div id="test1">
        div#test1 (oriinally)
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
       div#test2
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick='changeId()'>Set id value</button> OR
<button type="button" onclick="insertSpan()">insert new element</button>
```

It is possible to click both test buttons in the snippet and produce elements with duplicate ids - best avoided in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe this should work, if I understand your needs correctly:

```
const elementToObserve = document.querySelector("#parentElement");
const lookingFor = '#someID';
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
    if (document.querySelector(lookingFor)) {
        console.log(`${lookingFor} is ready`);
        observer.disconnect();
    }
});

observer.observe(elementToObserve, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

You will want to observe the parent of where you expect the element to appear. With the `subtree` and `childList` options set to true it will observe for changes there and fire callback once it spots any difference. And you can check in that callback if the element you are looking for is now on the page.